# Woocommerce import image from external URl

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce

For products in the shop client sent images as a URL, its an external URL, below is the one for reference
https://lilac.ecb.com.au/otherimage?product=NBF88SY.1&i=1

I've added this URL in CSV file on image column and tried to import it.
When I import its getting an error "Invalid image: Sorry, you are not allowed to upload this file type."

Any work arounds for this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your image link or file type.

By default, the following image file types are supported in WordPress: .jpeg, .jpg, .png, .gif, .ico. You are seeing the error because the image you are trying to upload does not have any of these file extensions, which is also obvious in your reference link `https://lilac.ecb.com.au/otherimage?product=NBF88SY.1&i=1`. The CSV product import expects the image links to be actual image links that end in a file name. Eg. .jpg, .png.

To make sure WooCommerce is detecting your product images, you can look for the Images column. You should see the URLs to your product images in the sample, as shown below.

[image]

Reference: [Error importing image](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-importing-image/)